# Add a div and take the coordinates

Tags: javascript

```js
$("#img_vaso").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).data("dragging", true);
});

$("#img_vaso").mouseup(function() {
    $(this).data("dragging", false);
});

$("#img_vaso").mousemove(function(e) {
    if (!$(this).data("dragging"))
        return;
    $(this).css("left", e.clientX - $(this).width()/2);
    $(this).css("top", e.clientY - $(this).height()/2);
});


function addElement()
{  
  const div = document.createElement('div'); 
  div.id = "img_vaso"; 
  div.style.width = "200px";
  div.style.height = "200px";
  div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://i.ibb.co/0nxDp58/img2.png)';   
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="content" style="width:800px; height:400px;border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; position: relative" >
<div id="img_vaso" style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/4JfMy4d/img1.png'); width:200px; height:200px; position: absolute; ">
</div> 
</div>

<button onClick=addElement()>ADD</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

hi everyone, I have this code, but it doesn't work.
if I move the first green image everything is fine.
Then if I add through ADD the red image does not move
In my project I'm stuck like this and I don't know how to proceed.
Can someone help me please ?
Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>     
<body>
<div id="my_area" style="width:500px; height:300px;">

</div>
<br>    
<button>ADD IMMAGE</button> 
<p><b>coordinates</b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're missing the event listeners inside the addElement function (these should refer only to the added element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things to consider in your code.
1.) The green image is directly inside of your HTML DOM. And JQuery will find it and add the necessary listeners. But when you click on the "Add" Button you are adding a new div element. The registration of mousedown, mousemove and mouseup will not be executed anymore. There is no listener added to the new div.

2.) I would not suggest to use the same ID a second time inside of your DOM since an ID should be unique.

3.) Top and Left usually require absolute or relative positioning. Add the css position to your newly created element too.

You can add the listeners to the div element instead of adding an already used ID to it.

Your Listener code could look like this:

```
function addElement()
{   
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  //You do not need to set an ID here
  div.style.width = "200px";
  div.style.height = "200px";
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.top = '200px'; //To see it at the beginning
  div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://i.ibb.co/0nxDp58/img2.png)';     
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);    

  //Register the listeners here. You can do that with or without jQuery
  div.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    $(e.target).data("dragging", true);
  });
  div.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    //You do not need $(e.target). You can achieve everything without jquery too.
    $this = $(e.target);
    $this.data("dragging", false);
  });
  div.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    console.log(e.target);
    $this = $(e.target);
    console.log($this);
    if (!$this.data("dragging"))
        return;
    $this.css("left", e.clientX - $this.width()/2);
    $this.css("top", e.clientY - $this.height()/2);
  });

}
```

NOTE: Instead of $('...') you can also use document.querySelector('...') or document.querySelectorAll('...'). In this case you would not need JQuery at all. Nowadays you can do nealry everything whithout jQuery. Try to avoid it except you really need it (e.g. when you have to support very old browsers)

Comment: yes that's fine. now I would have another doubt.in fact on the unique id, I was wrong, because I believe that every image must have its own id.
every time an image is added, I should also have the option to delete it. I had thought of a side box with the info of the image: name, position (left, top) and a delete button. Could you show me how I can do it? Thanks

Comment: hello an info
the instruction, div.style.backgroundImage = 'url (https://i.ibb.co/0nxDp58/img2.png)';
is it possible to upload an image whose name is linked to the button name?
example
button1 -> immage1
button2 -> immage2
the prefix is always the same but the number changes
the uploaded image must be tied to the button. I hope I have been as clear as possible

Comment: You can remove the element by calling parent.removeChild(child). Provide an ID or a class and select it when needed.
You can create differen IDs by concatenating a string: `div.id = 'img_vaso_' + (++index); `

The same mechanism can be used for your background image: `div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(i.ibb.co/0nxDp58/img' + (index) + '.png)';`

Do not forget to initialize the variable at the beginning `let index = 0;`